# Populate a ListView with texts and images from Amazon Web Services products?

Tags: android, mongodb, listview, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DB in AWS DynamoDB. In this DB, there are 3 text columns that I want to put in a ListView (one text from every column in each row).

Besides, I want to add an image to every row.

So, I have four questions:

1. Where should I store the images? On the S3 service?

2. Should I store the texts on DynamoDB table, or should I create a MongoDB instance on EC2 and access there? I'm asking since I'm still on the free tier, and I don't want to end my free read and write units.

3. How can I create a ListView that takes the texts from the DB, and the correct image?

4. If there is no image or one of text is N/A, how can I show a text of "N/A" instead of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using DynamoDBScanExpression and a BaseAdapter class. For the S3 images, I'm using the url of the image to decode it to a bitmap and set it as an ImageView in every row.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open question. Here is my suggestion:

1. Images should go to S3. DynamoDB isn't designed to store large binary data. It has per item size limitation and more expansive comparing to other storage services.
2. The SDK has S3Link which allows you to store image in S3 and metadata in DynamoDB for query. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/S3Link.html.
3. See above. You can get text and link to the image from DynamoDB.
4. See above. When link is null display N/A.